# Exclude files with no extension - XCOPY or ROBOCOPY

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, batch

I am trying to build a script that can copy folders, subfolders and contents from one drive to a backup drive. There are several files in each folder, subfolder. The condition I need to meet is that I only copy the files that have extensions, eg: "*.txt", "*.log", etc. The extensions vary from folder to folder, making it difficult to write all the extensions in a text file.
I was thinking of trying to exclude all files that have no extension, and copy all files that have any extension, as this is the requirement of the script. I have tried to do this, and it does not work. The batch script code is:
`xcopy "source_folder" "destination_folder" /s /i /exclude:"\."`

In addition, I have also tried to copy all files and then delete the files with no extensions, which works on a sample case, but is not viable since it will kill the network in terms of storage. The code is:

```
xcopy "source_folder" "destination_folder" /s /i
del /s "destination_folder\*."
```

I am very new to batch scripting, so any advice/ help is appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes it is better to go to a more conventional programming language than trying to work with the commands and multiple arcane arguments used by batch files. You could try [The C# Yellow Book teaches you programming from first principles](https://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book) as an introduction. Some of what it shows you at the start may seem irrelevant, but you need to build to an overall view of how to program sensibly. It is worth your time to study it :) Note that Visual Studio Community Edition is free of charge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will ignore files with no extension or only a one-character extension, which should work in most situations:

```
robocopy source destination /xf *.?

file.ext copied
file.ex  copied
file.e   ignored
file     ignored
```

Powershell example for running robocopy on directories with a specific name:

```
$Src = 'c:\source'
$Dst = 'c:\destination'

$Analysis = Get-ChildItem $Src -Directory -Recurse | 
  Where Name -like 'Analysis'

Foreach ($Folder in $Analysis) {
  # fix the destination path to be relative:
  $NewSrc = $Src -replace '\\','\\'
  $NewDst = $Folder.FullName -replace $NewSrc,$Dst

  # copy each Analysis folder using *.pdf
  Robocopy.exe $Folder.FullName $NewDst *.pdf
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution, and it worked for me. The only modification I made (which was not asked for), was adding the /E to ensure that the structure of directory including empty sub directories was maintained.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: if I wanted to modify the scope to say if a folder name within the directory is \Analysis, then robocopy source destination *.pdf, else robocopy source destination /xf *.? How would I go about doing that, if you are aware? Thanks!

Comment: @HemilMehulShah You could exclude that directory '/XD' with something like `robocopy [...] /XD Analysis`, then run a second `robocopy *.pdf` on only the Analysis directory. If my answer worked for you, consider marking it as the Answer, thanks!

Comment: This looks very promising. If I have many Analysis folders in the directory, is there a way to check the folder name, like if */Analysis, then robocopy *.pdf? I have tried looking for resources everywhere. Also my rating is only 11, so I have tried to mark your answer as the answer, but not able to

Comment: @HemilMehulShah you would need a more complicated script, as robocopy only takes one source. I'll add a powershell example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off

set "_destiny=C:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\Backpu\Folder"

2>nul cd /d "C:\The\Full\Path\To\Your\Folder" || exit /b

"%__AppDir__%robocopy.exe" .\. "%_destiny%" /xf *.? /is /s /l /z /njh /nfl
 
"%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" -1 | exit /b
```

---

Comment: I have not tried to implement this solution, but my understanding is that it will first delete all the files without extension, and then copy the rest to the backup folder, correct?
If that is the case, this approach would not work for my case, since we still want to retain all files, while only backing up the essential files incase the working copy is corrupted. 
Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: So is it a case of reversing the order of actions? Copies all files and then deletes at the source those that do not have an extension?

Comment: No. Sorry if I haven't been clear with the question. Let me try to explain better:
For example, we have a working directory that everyone has access to that is over 100gb . We want to create a backup from the working directory (source) and copy only the essential files to the backup (destination). The rest unnecessary files (no extension) need not be put in the destination, but still need to stay in the source. Thus, no deletion.