# Xcopy: Copy last modified file from folder

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, batch-file

I need to copy the last modified file of a particular extension from a folder. For example a folder contains:

- File1.cas
- File1.txt
- File2.cas
- File2.txt
- File3.cas
- File3.pptx
- ...
- File100.cas
- File100.pptx
- File100.doc

The date and time modified is the latest for file56.cas
I would like to copy only file56.cas, while copying files of other extensions as normal, and ignoring files with no extensions (the part already configured).

To ignore files with no extensions, I am using the solution found here:
[Exclude files with no extension - XCOPY or ROBOCOPY](https://superuser.com/q/1825514/1880541)
The specific code is:
`robocopy source destination /xf *.?`

Answer (score 0):

`xcopy` cannot copy only the latest file with a particular
extension.

The following (untested) batch code will copy the latest
`.cas` file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /od "path-to-folder\*.cas"') do set "LastFile=%%~i"
copy "path-to-folder\%LastFile%" "C:\target-folder\"
```

This code is intended to be used inside a `.bat` file.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "D:\Source\Folder" || exit 
set "_destiny=Z:\Destination\Folder"

for /f delims^= %%i in =;(' dir /b /a:-d /o:-d /tc *.cas '
     );= do copy "%%~dpnxi" "%_destiny%" /y /v & goto %:^(

%:^(
rem./ continue or & exit /b
```

---

**1.** List your files and a `for /f .. ( dir ...)do ...` loop

**2** Use the list by date, which by default shows from oldest to newest, then reverse the date order `/o-d`

**3.** Use the first file listed for your `copy` task, then exit without copying the rest of the files to be listed in the loop with `goto :label`

**4.** Continue your bat/codes or exit if there are no more executions `exit`